# Why does this while loop never stops in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop

I am trying to generate a list of 100 unique random numbers using Python 3.8. For this I am using the following block of code:

```
import random

list_1_unique = [random.randint(0,30)]


for i in range(1, 100):
    x = random.randint(0, 30)
    while x in list_1_unique:
        x = random.randint(0, 30)
    list_1_unique.append(x)
    
list_1_unique
```

But once I run it Ipython console never stops, so it enters in eternal loop and I do not understand why? Can anybody guess why?

Comment: when 'x' append to the list, list size get change

Comment: You generate a random number, then add it to a list, and then check if it is in that list. This will continue until you run out of memory.

Comment: I deleted the indentation in front of list_1_unique.append(x) and it still does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times you run the for loop is greater than the the number of possible different values you can get from your *randint*, so after 30 or so step your list *list_1_unique* will have all possible values and in the 31° step you get into an infinite loop because any value of x you generate will be in your list and thus you can't get out of the while loop.

In other words, you can't pick 100 objects from a box containing only 30.

If you want a sample of N random numbers better use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(1000),10)
[840, 872, 312, 952, 826, 867, 99, 4, 132, 745]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following condition is causing the infinite loop:

```
while x in list_1_unique
```

If x happens to be in the list when hitting the while loop the first time, you are gone. Since this is repeated 100 times, guess what, it's bound to happen.

Comment: If x is in list_1_unique I am updating the value of x so I think you are wrong.

Comment: @G.T. nope you are not changing the value of x in the list but adding a newer value.To change the previous value you would have to do `list_name[index] = new_value`.

Comment: @G.T. updating x and appending it to the list after exiting the while loop. The list keeps getting more and more values until there is no way to pick an x not in the list.